# How to create an order?

Tags: orders, magento1.9.2.4

I have form:

```
<form action="" class="ui-form">
    <h3>Быстрый заказ</h3>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="text" id="fastname" required autocomplete="off"><label for="fastname">Ваше имя</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="text" id="fastphone" required autocomplete="off"><label for="fastphone">Телефон</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="text" id="fastaddr" required autocomplete="off"><label for="fastaddr">Адрес доставки</label>
    </div>
    <p><input type="button" value="Заказать" onclick="fastorder(<?php echo  $this->getProduct()->getId()?>, <?php echo  $this->getProduct()->getPrice()?>)"></p>
</form>
```

And I have JavaScript that is called after I click a button on the form:

```
function fastorder(pr_id, pr_price){
    var pr_name = document.getElementById("fastname").value;
    var pr_phone = document.getElementById("fastphone").value;
    var pr_addr = document.getElementById("fastaddr").value;
    alert('ProductID:'+pr_id+'  Price:'+pr_price+'  Name:'+pr_name+'  Phone:'+pr_phone+'  Adress:'+pr_addr);
}
```

In the alert I get all the necessary information to create an order.

How to create an order help please?

I'm using (Magento 1.9.2.4)